# How to index translations of one item in Sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, solr, sunspot

I am using Sunspot/Solr to index my Rails website. I index City name by doing the following:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :name
    ...
  end
  ...
```

Now I am internationalizing the whole site, using the Globalize3 gem. It saves translations in another table, and get these translations out using the normal accessors.

From the example here (http://osdir.com/ml/rails-oceania/2011-11/msg00047.html) they have:

```
searchable do
  # sorting
  string(:job_title) { title }

  # keyword / fulltext searching
  I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|
    text(("title_" + locale.to_s).to_sym, :default_boost => 2)
      { eval("title_" + locale.to_s) }
  end
end
```

So essentially for each locale there is an indexing column in Sunspot, like title_en and title_fr. I am wondering if there is a better approach? (too many columns sounds bad to me)

One alternative I am thinking is  to concatenate translations of one item as a single string and put it in another text index column.

Also I was thinking if there is something similar to `integer :ids, :multiple => true` for texts?

So what's a better way to index multiple translations of the same item name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented single column language index:

```
LANGUAGES = {
  'en' => 'English',
  'fr' => 'Français'
}

#inside city model

text :name_alt do
  LANGUAGES.keys.reject{|l| l=='en'}.map do |locale|
    read_attribute(:name, locale:locale)
  end
end
```

This uses Rails I18n module and Globalize3. 'read_attribute' is part of Globalize3.

This avoids creating columns per language.

I am not sure whether this is better or the multi column approach.